# Como faço para criar um sinônimo de Tag?

Tags: suporte, tags-sinônimas

Como faço para criar um sinônimo de Tag? Já possuo mais de 1500 pontos mas não notei nenhum botão extra com esta finalidade.

Comment: Não vou colocar como resposta pois não tenho 1500 rep para testar se é igual, mas só pelas imagens do guia do SO EN deve ser possível encontrar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99990/how-do-you-create-tag-synonyms

Comment: Só para evitar possíveis dúvidas, o privilégio é adquirido ao obter 1250 pontos de reputação, e não 1500. Não corrigi seu texto pois ele não está errado, você ter escrito 1500 para enfatizar que já passou e muito da rep necessária para ganhar o privilégio, só estou comentado pois alguns usuários podem ser levados a confusão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não pode criar um sinônimo de tag por si só, o que você e qualquer outro usuário que adquiriu esse privilégio podem fazer é **sugerir** sinônimos de tag. Após a sugestão ser colocada os usuários com pontuação de pelo menos 5 na tag podem votar a favor ou contra a sugestão.

Por exemplo, clique na [suporte](/questions/tagged/suporte), depois clique em "sinônimos", você será levado para [**essa página**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suporte/synonyms). Lá tem a explicação completa:

> Os usuários com reputação de mais de 1250 e uma pontuação total de respostas de 5 ou mais na tag podem **sugerir** sinônimos de tags. Os usuários com uma pontuação total de respostas (o total de votos a favor menos o total de votos contra) de 5 ou mais na tag podem **votar** em sinônimos para a tag. As sugestões serão aprovadas automaticamente quando alcançarem a pontuação de 4 e excluídas automaticamente quando atingirem a pontuação de -2.

Indo [**nessa tela**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) você pode ver todos sinônimos de tags sugeridos e os pendentes do SOPT, e eis aqui um [**link direto**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/busca/synonyms) para uma sugestão aberta para votação.